# When knitting an Rmd file to pdf, hashtags in links to bookdown books are converted to %23 and don't work

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

When I knit the following Rmd file to pdf, the `#` in the link to the bookdown book is converted to `%23` and doesn't work. The link works fine if the Rmd is knitted to html instead of pdf.

I tried escaping the `#` with `\` and `\\`; neither worked.

```
---
output: pdf_document
urlcolor: blue
---

This link does not work in the rendered pdf:

https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-syntax.html#inline-formatting
```

Is there any way to get such a link to work in a rendered pdf document?

Comment: Try encasing the link in `\url{}` like this: `\url{https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-syntax.html#inline-formatting}`, and see if that works. You may have to include `\usepackage{hyperref}` in your `.Rmd` as well.

Comment: @JustinSingh Thanks for the suggestion... just tried, doesn't work.

Comment: Might be an issue with the PDF viewer? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555559/href-broken-links-due-to-url-encoding-hash-sign-23

Comment: That's it, thank you! If you write this as an answer, I'll check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, it's an issue with the PDF Viewer.

Reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555559/href-broken-links-due-to-url-encoding-hash-sign-23